# How to get Title / Description from Facebook Reels?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping

I am scraping my saved Facebook reels, which is going well, but I am trying to also capture the title or description of the video to insert into the database, as well as for the filename. When I use this API: `facebook-reel-and-video-downloader.p.rapidapi.com`, I don't get the info.

When I try to use Javascript and go straight to the page, I don't get anything. Any ideas how to capture that info? Here is an example of something I have tried. I have tried pasting into the console of Firefox and Chrome, but all I get back is a ton of javascript that would be used to eventually build the page, after it authenticated everything.

```
(function(ns, fetch) {
  if (typeof fetch !== 'function') return;

  ns.fetch = function() {
    var out = fetch.apply(this, arguments);
    
    // side-effect
    out.then(function(response) {
        // When the page is loaded convert it to text
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(html) {
        // Initialize the DOM parser
        var parser = new DOMParser();

        // Parse the text
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

        console.log(doc);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {  
        console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);  
    })
    return out;
  }

}(window, window.fetch));
fetch('https://www.facebook.com/reel/1340650889956366');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Apify, you can get those informations from Facebook Reel Scraper.
https://apify.com/jeremy_frost/facebook-reel-scraper